# Upload Zip files to ASP.NET Core WebAPI service with HttpClient but IFormData argument is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

like the title says, I'm trying to upload a .zip from my WPF application to my .NET Core Web API.

After some research I found out that it is possible to be done with using MultiPartDataContent and sending it that way.

The code for sending the data to the server looks like this:

```
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62337/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                string filepath = @"C:\Users\uic10950\Desktop\Meeting2Text\RecordingApp\bin\mixedaudio.zip";
                string filename = "mixedaudio.zip";

                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));

                fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename };
                content.Add(fileContent);

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/transcriptions/recording", content);
                string returnString = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
            }
```

On the server side my controller action looks like this:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddFileToTranscription([FromForm] IFormFile file)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
                return Ok(content);
            }
        }
```

This action code will be changed as soon as I get the file upload working

From what I've understood while researching, my file should be found in the:

> [FromForm] IFormFile

file attribute of the action, but unfortunately it is null.

Comment: Have you tried it without `[FromForm]`?

Comment: @Ali Bahrami Still the same problem, it stays null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing a couple of things wrong:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFileToTranscription([FromForm] IFormFile file)
```

❌ You don't need `[FromFile]` attribute.

❌ Your file argument name is `file` but you haven't defined it when you are uploading files, in the client.

❌ You don't need to add `ContentDisposition` and set it as `attachment` because it's for the response, not the request! (1)

---

✅ Server:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddFileToTranscription( IFormFile file)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        var content = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        return Ok(content);
    }
}
```

✅ Client:

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:62337/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string filepath = @"C:\Users\uic10950\Desktop\Meeting2Text\RecordingApp\bin\mixedaudio.zip";
string filename = "mixedaudio.zip";

MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath));

// ➡ ✅ important change fileContent, form-input-name, real-file-name
content.Add(fileContent, "file", filename);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/transcriptions/recording", content);
string returnString = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
```

`MultipartFormDataContent.Add` method has a couple of overloads for adding form-data, you must use this [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_MultipartFormDataContent_Add_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_String_System_String_):

```
public void Add (System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, string name, string fileName);
```

---

Conclusion:

Whatever your `IFormData` argument is, you need to upload or send requests whit that name!

---

1. In a regular HTTP response, the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header is a header indicating if the content is expected to be displayed inline in the browser, that is, as a Web page or as part of a Web page, or as an attachment, that is downloaded and saved locally.

Comment: This is just what I needed, thanks for such a well structured and detailed answer.